# Issue in looping stdClass Object in Php

Tags: php, json

I am facing strange issue in looping json object using php. Here is the format of my data

```
stdClass Object
(
[userform] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 69
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 70
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 71
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 72
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 73
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 74
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 75
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 76
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 77
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 78
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 79
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [11] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 80
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [12] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 81
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [13] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 82
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [14] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 83
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [15] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 84
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [16] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 85
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [17] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 86
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [18] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 87
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [19] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 88
                [product] => testuser
            )

        [20] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 89
                [product] => testuser
            )

    )

)
```

But this loop throws following error.

**Trying to get property of non-object in**

Please let me know how to read the **product**  property value from the above format

Thanks all

Comment: You have a typo: `if(isset($roow`

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos that's another error, but the `if(isset($roow` always return false he/she has other error to find

Comment: you mean `$data->userform as $key=>$row` ?

Comment: yeah that is typo mistake, but always else condition is exectued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That foreach should be on `$data->userform` , not just `$data`

```
foreach($data->userform as $key=>$row){
             if(isset($row->product)){
               print_r($key);
               print_r($row->product);  
             }else{
               //product property is not set
             }
         }
```

Comment: Am getting same error, I have edited question with $data  variable fomat.

Comment: It is not possible to get that error anymore if that structure is 100% same like you mentioned, with same names.

Comment: Yeah it is not throwing error, but how can I read product property value from that data format

Comment: You can only read it if it is set, how can you read something if it is not set? so your `print_r($row->product); ` has to go inside that `if`, not inside that `else`. see the edit